# How do I get the bundle id of a different target?

Tags: xcode, target, ios8, nsbundle

I've added an extension.  The main code needs to tell `NCWidgetController` that there is content for the extension.  How do I programmatically lookup the extension's bundle ID from my main target?

Comment: It must be impossible.

Comment: Possible Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794613/get-bundle-id-from-a-different-target

Comment: just a thought. Have you tried `myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Library/MyBundle.bundle"];`?